# Uniform limit of continuous functions bounded variation

Tags: analysis, continuity, bounded-variation

Prove or disprove that if $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is the uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions each of which is of bounded variation, then $f$ is of bounded variation on $[a,b].$

Comment: Well, every continuous function is the uniform limit of a sequence of polynomials.

Comment: and a counter example would then be $x\sin(1/x)$ on $[0,1]$ with jose27's remark, right?

Comment: Yes, assuming without loss of generality that $a=0$ and $b=1$. We can also take any continuous function which is not of bounded variation.

Answer (score 2):

The result is false as stated: Take any continuous function not of bounded variation and approximate via polynomials (Weierstrass' theorem).

On the other hand if, for example, we had $V_a^b(f_n) \leq M$ for some constant $M>0$ and all $n$ then the result is true because $V_a^b(f) \leq \liminf_n V_a^b(f_n)$. To see this just pick a partition $(x_i)$ of $[a,b]$ and compute
$$
\sum_i |f_n(x_i)-f_n(x_{i-1})| \leq V_a^b(f_n).
$$
Now just take $\liminf_n$ on both sides and then the supremum over all partitions to conclude. Notice that this only needs a pointwise convergent sequence $f_n$.

Comment: So, since the way the question is asked is that each of these $f_n$'s actually IS of bounded variation, so are you saying that this is true?  And in face, you only need pointwise for it to be true?  Or are you saying that it's not true as we have uniform and not pointwise?

Comment: @Alyse: No, the result is false if we only ask the $f_n$ to be of bounded variation and $f_n\to f$ uniformly. It is true, however, if we ask the $f_n$ to have uniformly bounded variation.